# wildfly.maven.plugin deploys nothing if packaging is set to pom

Tags: maven, wildfly-maven-plugin

I am using Maven in order to automatically *download a dependency*, *set up (and start) the JBoss server* and *deploy that downloaded dependency* there. I created a `pom.xml`, which uses several Maven-Plugins. For **JBoss-related** interactions I am using the **wildfly-maven.plugin** (currently version 2.0.1.Final).

Since I am not building an artifact, but rather downloading it, I am not really producing a JAR (or any archived artifact).

The problem I currently have is: the **wildfly-maven-plugin does not seem to do anything if *packaging* is set to *pom***.

As a workaround I currently set the project packaging to JAR and added the following to prevent the project JAR from building:

```
<properties>
    <jar.skipIfEmpty>true</jar.skipIfEmpty>
    <maven.install.skip>true</maven.install.skip>
</properties>
```

---

**Update 04.03**
This is what my pom.xml basically looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>some.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>~y</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <maven.install.skip>true</maven.install.skip>
        <jar.skipIfEmpty>true</jar.skipIfEmpty>

        <plugin.wildfly.version>2.0.1.Final</plugin.wildfly.version>
        <plugin.wildfly.jboss-home>D:\server\jboss-eap-7.1</plugin.wildfly.jboss-home>
        <plugin.wildfly.hostname>localhost</plugin.wildfly.hostname>
        <plugin.wildfly.port>9990</plugin.wildfly.port>
        <plugin.wildfly.debug.port>9991</plugin.wildfly.debug.port>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.wildfly.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jboss-home>${plugin.wildfly.jboss-home}</jboss-home>
                    <id>local-jboss</id>
                    <hostname>${plugin.wildfly.hostname}</hostname>
                    <port>${plugin.wildfly.port}</port>
                    <filename>y.ear</filename>
                    <force>true</force>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-ear</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I will give `deploy-artifact` a try, but in general I'd expect the **wildfly.maven.plugin** to work even if `<packaging>` is set to `pom`.

Maven command on commandline to build it: `mvn clean install`.

My real pom.xml is a bit more complex, but if it'd work using this simple pom.xml, I could make it work in the more complex one that I use.

Comment: Showing your workaround code does not tell us anything about your problem code! Post at least the relevant parts of your problem code - so your wildfly-maven-plugin configuration - and how you are calling it.

Comment: I just added a simplified pom.xml call. Hope it helps.

Comment: You just want the EAR deployed right? If that's the case then you'd want to set `<skip>true</skip>` in the parent pom and set it to `false` in the EAR pom. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFMP-115 may be of interest to you as well.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins - yes. But unfortunately I am *not* building the EAR myself. I am just downloading it - which is why I cannot do what you suggested (even though it does make sense). I **might** be building other components, which will be built and deployed onto the same server at a later date (which is why I decided to use Maven altogether).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wildfly-maven-plugin` does not seem to do anything if packaging is set to `pom`. Using the packaging-type `jar` along with `jar.skipIfEmpty` helps.

When using `wildfly-maven-plugin`'s `deploy-only` goal, publishing works (through the management interface).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`deploy-artifact`](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/2.0.1.Final/deploy-artifact-mojo.html) goal. There is an [example](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/2.0.1.Final/examples/deployment-example.html#Deploying_other_artifacts) of it in the documentation.

Comment: Sadly assigning deploy-artifact as a goal (instead of deploy-only, see the simplified `pom.xml` above) and using `<packaging>` set to *pom* does not work (while keeping it at *jar* option does). Apparently deploy-artifact requires group-, version- and artifact-ID, which I supplied in the same way as I did to the maven-dependency-plugin (omitted in the example above for brevity reasons).